# How do I report Checkstyle results as pull-request annotations in Github Actions?

Tags: gradle, github, continuous-integration, checkstyle, github-actions

I have a Gradle build that I'm trying to move to Github Actions. I've found a starter workflow that runs the Gradle build on a commit but I haven't found a way to report the Checkstyle errors as pull-request annotations.

https://help.github.com/en/actions/language-and-framework-guides/building-and-testing-java-with-gradle

Is there an off the self way to report all Checktyle XML warnings and errors as pull-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search led me to this action: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/run-java-checkstyle

Haven't tried it myself, but worth a shot to use as a base if it doesn't work out.